# lxml requests on repl.it

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying lxml requests on [Replit](https://repl.it/Eqra/0) and I don't understand why it isn't working. The program doesn't stop running until the max retries, where I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "python", line 6, in 
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.presidency.ucsb.edu', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ws/index.php?pid=29400.html (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

my code is quite straightforward:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=29400.html'

r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

text = tree.xpath('//span[@class="displaytext"]/text()')

print(text)
```

How can I get this to run? I'm trying to get the content of that website, located in the "displaytext" span class. I've been using [this Python guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) for reference.

Python version 3.5

Comment: when I run your code I do get output: ```>>> print text
["HOWARD K. SMITH, MODERATOR: Good evening. The television and radio stations of the United States and their affiliated stations are proud to provide facilities for a discussion of issues in the current political campaign by the two major candidates for the presidency. The candidates need no introduction. The Republican candidate, ...etc...``` did you install the requests module via pip? python version? (mine was 2.7)

Comment: ps: I was working directly in python. the repl.it doesn't allow me to import requests

Comment: So the issue is with pulling requests in repl.it. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Repl.it and this is a limitation with our platform. We don't currently allow outgoing network requests.

Comment: Can I ask why? Is it something you plan to support someday somehow?

Comment: Is there any other online IDE which supports outgoing requests?

Comment: @AlanPallath, pythonanywhere you can. But you need to pay/signup, but it's relatively inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

switching to answer since it allows me to better line out things.

Have a look at the html of the website your are targeting. With this command you are selecting only 1 specific tag:

```
text = tree.xpath('//span[@class="displaytext"]/text()')
```

points to a specific span with class "displaytext"

You could change your code to:

```
text = tree.xpath('//span[@class="displaytext"]/..')
for element in text[0]:
    print element
```

This would select the span with class "displaytext" then select the parent of that span. And inside the for loop you would print all children of that parent.

Now it also shows the real problem: the paragraph elements are not in that list. Sorry, don't know an answer for that.