# Why can't I open a URL in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

I am unable to open a URL in Python3.
I am using an online editor named Repl.it for coding (https://repl.it/languages/python3)

**Code:**

```
import urllib.request
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
mybytes = fp.read()
print(mybytes)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lxml requests on repl.it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162897/lxml-requests-on-repl-it)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment. 
I am able to replicate the problem on Repl.it.
It seems to come from Repl.it. I do not have problem executing your code directly from python prompt In my computer.